# How to retrieve all child and subchild elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some sort of mechanisam that will give me this: after I click on parent -> give me all child values. -> Click on a child value -> give me all subchild values.

```
Item <- click on it          Item <- click on it
--------------------         --------------------
Item1 <- click on it   OR    Item1
Item2                        Item2 <- click on it
--------------------         --------------------
Item11                       Item21
```

I guess this would be html code:

```
<div id="item"> Hello I am <strong>Item</strong>, click on me! I will give you <strong>Item1</strong> and <strong>Item2</strong>
    <div id="item1"> Hello I am <strong>Item1</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item11</strong>
        <div id="item11"> Hello I am <strong>Item11</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2"> Hello I am <strong>Item2</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item21</strong>!
        <div id="item21">Hello I am <strong>Item21</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: jQuery children is not what you want? https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: The desired result is not so clear? Could you explain more!

Comment: I would not recommend using ID's for this, use something more semantic. Whether that is parent and child classes of some description, or using `<ul>` and `<li>`'s is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Jquery selector, the following code should work:

```
var children = $(element).children();
```

Just replace element with whatever selector you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$('div').click(function() {
  var c = $(this).children();
  console.log(c.text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">Hello I am <strong>Item</strong>, click on me! I will give you <strong>Item1</strong> and <strong>Item2</strong>
  <div id="item1">Hello I am <strong>Item1</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item11</strong>
    <div id="item11">Hello I am <strong>Item11</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item2">Hello I am <strong>Item2</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item21</strong>!
    <div id="item21">Hello I am <strong>Item21</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find next `elements` till a `div` start using jQuery `.nextUntill`

```
$('strong').on('click', function() {
    var nexts = $(this).nextUntil('div');
})
```

```js
$('strong').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).nextUntil('div').length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">Hello I am <strong>Item</strong>, click on me! I will give you <strong>Item1</strong> and <strong>Item2</strong>
  <div id="item1">Hello I am <strong>Item1</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item11</strong>
    <div id="item11">Hello I am <strong>Item11</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item2">Hello I am <strong>Item2</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item21</strong>!
    <div id="item21">Hello I am <strong>Item21</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this  https://jsfiddle.net/bnyjmp4c/

```
 <div id="item"> Hello I am <strong>Item</strong>, click on me! I will give you <strong>Item1</strong> and <strong>Item2</strong>
 <div id="item1"> Hello I am <strong>Item1</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item11</strong>
    <div id="item11"> Hello I am <strong>Item11</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
 </div>
 <div id="item2"> Hello I am <strong>Item2</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item21</strong>!
    <div id="item21">Hello I am <strong>Item21</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="children-show-div">
</div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("div").on("click", function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 var html ="";
  $(this).find("> div").each(function() {
     html += $(this).attr("id") + "<br/>";
  })

   $(".children-show-div").html(html)
  })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('div').on("click", function(ev){
  var $children = $(this).children("div"); // get the children of type div
  // or var $children = $(this).find("div"); // to get the children and their sub children ...
  
  // test:
  $children.each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  });
  
  // stop the event from bubbling up
  ev.stopPropagation();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="item">Hello I am <strong>Item</strong>, click on me! I will give you <strong>Item1</strong> and <strong>Item2</strong>
  <div id="item1">Hello I am <strong>Item1</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item11</strong>
    <div id="item11">Hello I am <strong>Item11</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="item2">Hello I am <strong>Item2</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item21</strong>!
    <div id="item21">Hello I am <strong>Item21</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is based on analyzing the [event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/).

The [event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is:

> The DOM element that initiated the event
>
> The target property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare event.target to this in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when events bubble

So, because your div has an id I propose to listen for all click events related to that div:

```js
$('#item').on('click', function(e) {
  //
  // If clicked outside the div (i.e.: on a strong tag) 
  // get the corresponding div element
  //
  var ele = e.target.tagName == 'DIV' ? 
         $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest('div');
  //
  // get all div children belonging to current ele
  //
  ele.children('div').each(function() {
    console.log(this.id);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="item"> Hello I am <strong>Item</strong>, click on me! I will give you <strong>Item1</strong> and <strong>Item2</strong>
    <div id="item1"> Hello I am <strong>Item1</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item11</strong>
        <div id="item11"> Hello I am <strong>Item11</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="item2"> Hello I am <strong>Item2</strong>. Click on me I will give you <strong>Item21</strong>!
        <div id="item21">Hello I am <strong>Item21</strong>, there is no more element after me.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```